# Assigning weightages to variables

Tags: regression

I have three variables which impact my output, however, I want to statistically establish weightage of each variable in determining/influencing the output. I have significant data points for the three variables that can be plotted.

Output = x* V1 + y* V2 + z* V3. Here, I want to determine x, y and z.

Can you suggest what approach should be adopted here?

Comment: Are you looking for linear regression?

Answer (score 1):

First, the usual way to write this is $Y = b_0 + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + b_3X_3$

Second, it seems clear you want some form of regression. Which form will depend, primarily, on the nature of the output variable Y and the nature of the data. Re Y:  Is it continuous? Is it dichotomous? Is it ordinal?

If it is continuous, the usual starting place would be multiple linear regression; you would then have to check the assumptions.

Re The data: The main question is whether it is independent.